# Gas Water Heat + Dryer - Can a gas dryer and washing machine be placed next to a gas water heater?

Tags: water-heater, dryer, gas

Looking to move the dryer and washer in my garage next to the water heater.

Are there any restriction regarding the surroundings of a gas water heater?
Can a gas dryer be placed next to a gas water heater?
Can a gas dryer be stacked on top of a washing machine?

Comment: @Ruskes, the poster did not say they were going to do the work; they were asking whether the desired physical arrangement was possible.

Comment: @Ruskes  it varies by jurisdiction.   Some places allow it, State of Washington allows homeowners to do gas work.   That said, it's certainly best practice to have a pro work on gas piping but in some areas, not against code to have a home owner do it.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson and you need special equipment to test for leaks

Comment: Gas Water Heater and Gas Dryer both need good unobstructed air supply, and exhausts. Who is going to do the gas work ? Stacking is allowed if using special frame made for that so they physically do not sit on top of each other.

Comment: @Ruskes   I'm not going to argue with you about this.   In King County (the largest county  in Washington state specifically allows homeowners, friends, relatives to do  or help install plumbing including gas as long as they are not paid.  If paid, they need to be licensed.   Regarding "special testing equipment"  for many years that consisted of slathering soapy water over connections and see if you got bubbles.   Natural gas pressure is very very low, only about 1 -1.5 PSI.  The other testing equipment would be a persons nose since nat gas and propane is odorized.   ..continues...

Comment: From  King county web site:  https://kingcounty.gov/depts/health/environmental-health/piping/plumbing/installer.aspx

**Can I do my own gas piping work?**
Property owners can install gas piping on property they own. If you are paying to have gas piping work done, the installer is required to be a registered contractor or be employed by a registered contractor. Please note that within the City of Seattle only, a gas pipe installer must be the property owner, or they must hold a Seattle Gas Piping Mechanic License. You can find more information regarding this on the City of Seattle's website.

Comment: @Ruskes The checking for leaks part is the easy part and does *not* require special equipment - just a spray bottle with soap/water and a good eye for bubbles. There are however a *lot* of other things involved - using the right type of connectors (e.g., some water pipe connectors might fit but not be rated for gas), knowing where to use different types of pipe, where to use drip legs, where to install cutoffs, etc. - it is a non-trivial trade with big consequences if done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few pieces to the question:

- Gas Water Heater

A gas water heater typically will have requirements for clearance (should be specified by the manufacturer in the installation manual), for exhaust (typically metal with specific dimensions, and for combustion air. In a quick search, I found a typical Rheem with specifications of 3" clearance in front, 1" on the sides and 12" on the top. So really very little clearance needed - as long as "next to" really means "a few inches away", there is unlikely to be a problem.

- Gas Dryer

A gas dryer should have clearance specified in the manual. I suspect the key issues are front (door) and back (exhaust) because washers and dryers are often placed side-by-side. The exhaust for a gas dryer *must* be done properly. Even with an electric dryer (lint and hot/humid air) there are concerns about making sure the ductwork is connected and sealed properly with a minimum of bends, etc. With gas it is even more critical as the exhaust will include combustion products - CO2 (Carbon Dioxide) guaranteed and the potential for CO (Carbon Monoxide) which is extremely dangerous.

- Stacking

This is likely to be a much bigger problem. I would not recommend stacking any washer and dryer unless the manufacturer actually designed the appliances to be stacked. The risks if something goes wrong are huge. With other appliances (e.g., if you wanted to stick a freezer up on a shelf) the primary concern would simply be whether the appliance would be secure and not fall on someone. But with any appliance involving water (leaks) or gas (leaks, heat, etc.) there are many more risks. If you happen to have appliances designed to be stacked or separate then you should be able to get a kit from the manufacturer to convert from separate to stacked (some mechanical, possibly electrical as well so that the washer plugs into the dryer (or vice versa) which then plugs into the wall).

Comment: Thank you Manassehkatz-Moving